# pandas dataframe merge column with same name and data separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the dataframe is looking like

let's say this df1

```
teamname  player.1  player.2  player.3
xyz        abc        nan       def
gh1        nan        hgf       jnr
oed        jeo        nan       nan
```

output should be like

let's say this df2

```
teamname player
xyz       abc
          def
gh1       hgf
          jnr
oed       jeo
```

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long`.

Comment: what will be the argument in wide_to_long

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: I had already used wide_to_long function but the output i need is not matching with result. That's y I asked for an argument. And the problem statement which i have , and the question that i asked is just 5-10% of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if 'player' in col.lower()] #Your player column names

df_parts = [] # List to store mini-dfs
for col in player_cols:
    df_auxiliary = df1[['teamname', col]]
    df_auxiliary = df_auxiliary.rename(columns={col:'Players'})
    df_auxiliary = df_auxiliary.dropna()
    df_parts.append(df_axuliary)

df2 = pd.concat(df_parts) # Create final df
```

Or in "one line":

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames='player', i=['teamname'], j='player_num')
df2 = df2.dropna()
```

Comment: in my question column name is player.1, according to your answer if I replace player_1, player_2, with player.1 and player.2. It shows an error

Comment: Check now with a list comprehension.

Comment: df2 = df2.dropna(all) give this error ValueError: No axis named <built-in function all> for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: My bad, the all param was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for `melt()`, it is pretty generic:

```
  teamname player.1 player.2 player.3
0      xyz      abc      NaN      def
1      gh1      NaN      hgf      jnr
2      oed      jeo      NaN      NaN
```

resulting in

```
df.melt(id_vars=['teamname'], value_name='player').dropna().drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values(['teamname'], ascending=False).set_index('teamname')


         player
teamname       
xyz         abc
xyz         def
oed         jeo
gh1         hgf
gh1         jnr
```

The part coming behind melt removes the NaNs, drops a column we don't need and sorts the dataframe. FInally we set `teamname` as index.

Comment: It will not work if I add any column in df1 with name let's say keeper and put some random values in it. And I need df2 with the format that I mention in question.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree. When you add another column, e.g. `keeper` with some values, then it will also be melted in the new dataframe. In fact, everything other than what is given in `id_vars` will be melted.
You could add a `value_vars = [c for c in df.columns if "player" in c.lower()]` to make sure to only include "players".
What format are you refering to? The order of `teamname`?

Comment: okay i got it thanks for helping me